# What would be a good example of a "linked list" in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am trying to teach myself programming and have just encountered the concept of arrays vs. linked lists.  I would imagine list() and np.array() all are considered to be arrays.  I have heard that the collections package has a object type deque that is a linked list.  Are there other linked lists in Python?  Would a Python dictionary, dict(), be a linked list or an array?

Thanks!

Comment: `list` is a list. It is implemented as an array list. But it is not an array. `collections.dequeue` is sort of a linked-list, specifically, it is a doubly-linked list of "blocks". [There are some informative comments in the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1b293b60067f6f4a95984d064ce0f6b6d34c1216/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L33). Note, linked list vs array isn't an all-encompassing binary, they are two of a myriad of different data structures that exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would imagine list() and np.array() all are considered to be arrays.

Correct.

> I have heard that the collections package has a object type deque that is a linked list.

Mostly correct. It is specifically a linked list of arrays, to reduce memory overhead. See [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a86b522d8f1c8b9c26b5550de221d2227158cf4d/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L33).

> Are there other linked lists in Python?

I don't think there are in Python core, but I could be wrong. It is [trivial](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Singly-linked_list/Element_definition#Python) to make one, though one would typically never do it.

> Would a Python dictionary, dict(), be a linked list or an array?

Neither. It is a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) with open addressing.